# `CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) - failed to create global data` warning in vim

Tags: copy-paste, vi

I just installed vim using brew

```
$ brew install vim
```

I am on a ssh connection to a MacOSX desktop. I am heavily using `homebrew`.

As soon as try to delete a character or copy something in vim, I get the following warning message:

`[15020] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data`

I suspect the vim is not able to access system clipboard.

There is ticket on macport (https://lists.macports.org/pipermail/macports-tickets/2016-May/205983.html), it looks like that it wasn't resolved.

I installed [fakeclip](https://github.com/kana/vim-fakeclip) plugin in vim but it didn't help either.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this annoyance over ssh connection?

**UPDATE**

```
$ sudo -u dilawars vi filename
```

works great. So it is almost certain that issue is with access to clipboard.

Comment: I still get the issue even with sudo -u

Comment: I got the same error. I was able to work around it. My info may provide some clues to your problem.

I had a GNU screen session open in Terminal.  I logged off.  When I logged back on and reattach to the screen session (screen -r), pbcopy in the screen session's bash shells started getting the above error. Also, "open some_file" now hung.  sudo didn't work either:

sudo pbcopy <some_file
sudo: unknown uid: 502   # 502 is my uid

If I start a new GNU screen session: everything works.

Your copy/delete/clipboard problem in vim via ssh to remote OSX machine seems related.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/andyshinn/dd6cabc38194e57d4014d291a03a1995 have some useful suggestions. `pbcopy` works but now `pbpaste` generates the same error.